# Hyperlink in Gridview in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I want to extract the article id from a gridview row when I click on the hyperlink. My goal is to be able to capture the article id field of a specific row when I click on the hyperlink in gridview.

This is what I tried so far but for some reason, it doesn't go to the codebehind when I click on the hyperlink.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Rssfeed" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="grid_RowCommand" CssClass="Grid">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Info">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    Articleid:
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#Eval("articleid") %>' runat="server" />
                    <br />
                    Title :
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%#Eval("title") %>' runat="server" />
                    <br />
                    Link:
                  <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkFile"  runat="server" target="_blank" CommandName="Select" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("link") %>' Text='<%# Eval("link") %>'></asp:HyperLink>                 <br />
                     Publicationdate:
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%#Eval("publicationdate") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>



public void grid_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        // If multiple ButtonField column fields are used, use the
        // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
            // property to an Integer.
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            // Get the last name of the selected author from the appropriate
            // cell in the GridView control.
            GridViewRow selectedRow = Rssfeed.Rows[index];
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that the Hyperlink won't perform a postback. if you need to postback you have to use a LinkButton

Answer (score 0):

This example can help:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   Link:
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbFile" CommandName="Select" runat="server"><%# Eval("link") %></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

code behind

```
public void Rssfeed_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            // get text from LinkButton e.g. URL as in question
            string link = ((LinkButton)selectedRow.FindControl("lbFile")).Text;

            // Redirect to the URL link
            Response.Redirect(link);
        }
    }
```